# How to find all non-refunded products a stripe customer has bought?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the Stripe API to determine all of the products a customer of mine has bought but has not had refunded.

More specifically, I'm offering a lifetime membership to my users as a one time purchase. I'd like to find out if a given customer has purchased this product.

I've looked through the charges and payment intent APIs and haven't found a way to link either of them back to a product or price. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using Checkout, the Session object has a `line_items` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) that shows the specific [product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price-product) purchased on that Session, `line_items.data.price.product`. To attain this level of data, you’ll need to pass the `expand: [‘data.line_items’]` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) to your call to [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) Checkout Sessions.

If you are not using Checkout, then the other option is to add the product id/ name as a metadata when creating the [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-metadata) or the [Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-metadata). [Metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) allows you to attach key-value data to these objects and store this additional information so you can easily identify what product a given customer purchased. You can then list the [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-customer)/ [Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-customer) by that customer and look at the metadata on that transaction to see the product purchased.

Comment: There must be another method for payment intents because in the stripe dashboard they manage to display the list of products purchased for a given payment intent.